# AdMob crashing when using my own Ad Unit ID

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, crash, admob

i have just created an adMob account and an ad unit for my app, but when i use that ad unit ID in my app in Xcode it launches fine but after 5 seconds it throws an exception, but it works fine with the test ad unit ID, have anyone experienced this and have solution?

EDIT: 
My app is not on App Store yet (If this has something to do with it)

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found out why this was happening. I was running it on the simulator and as soon i tested my app on my iPhone there was no problem and the ads was working fine.